# Powershell - Check on Remote Process, if done continue

Tags: powershell

As part of a backup operation, I am running the 7zip command to compress a folder into a single .7z file. No problems there as I am using the `InVoke-WMIMethod`.

Example:

```
$zip = "cmd /c $irFolder\7za.exe a $somedirectory.7z $somedirectory"
"InVoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList $zip -ComputerName $remotehost"
```

My problem comes in as my script continues, the 7za.exe process hasn't completed. I am then attempting to copy the item off of the remote system and it is either incomplete or fails.

Can someone point me in the direction to figure out how to identify if the 7za.exe process is still running, wait until it is dead, then proceed with the rest of my script?

I can grasp pulling the process from the remote system via...

```
get-wmiobject -class Win32_Process -ComputerName $remotehost | Where-Object $_.ProcessName -eq "7za.exe"}
```

Not sure how to turn that into usable info for my issue.

**Answer UPDATE:** (thx to nudge by @dugas)

This will do it with some feedback for those that need it...

```
do {(Write-Host "Waiting..."),(Start-Sleep -Seconds 5)}
until ((Get-WMIobject -Class Win32_process -Filter "Name='7za.exe'" -ComputerName $target | where {$_.Name -eq "7za.exe"}).ProcessID -eq $null)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can invoke the Wait-Process cmdlet on the remote computer with the Invoke-Command cmdlet. Example:

```
$process = Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name create -ArgumentList notepad -ComputerName RemoteComputer

Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputer -ScriptBlock { param($processId) Wait-Process -ProcessId $processId } -ArgumentList $process.ProcessId
```

Since you mentioned using Invoke-Command is not an option, another option is polling.
Example:

```
$process = Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name create -ArgumentList notepad -ComputerName hgodasvccr01
$processId = $process.ProcessId

$runningCheck = { Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId='$processId'" -ComputerName hgodasvccr01 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { ($_.ProcessName -eq 'notepad.exe') } }

while ($null -ne (& $runningCheck))
{
 Start-Sleep -m 250
}

Write-Host "Process: $processId is not longer running"
```

Comment: I did look at Invoke-Command, however at this point utilizing winrm is not an option for me on the remote systems. Hoping in the future it will. I apologize I didn't include that info...

Comment: Alright I am giving you credit..you got me on the right track. Again..I Get-Process doesn't work in this case, but I did find using Get-WMIObject worked nicely.  do {(Write-Host "Waitng..."),(Start-Sleep -Seconds 5)}
until ((Get-WMIobject -Class Win32_process -ComputerName $target | where {$_.Name -eq "7za.exe"}).ProcessID -eq $null)

Comment: @c3uba9wfaq - Sorry, my bad, forgot that Get-Process was using something you can't - I adjusted my answer to use Get-WmiObject. Notice the filter parameter on the Get-WmiObject cmdlet, without that, you are returning all results. I also moved the logic that checks if the process is running into a scriptblock so that it would be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with a do... while loop that just sleeps until the process is finished.

```
 do { 
    "waiting"
    start-sleep 10 
    } while (gwmi -class win32_process -ComputerName $remotehost | Where ProcessName -eq "7za.exe")
```

Comment: Note that one issue with doing this is you may be waiting on a process   that you didn't start. Another issue may be efficiency, as to check the while condition you have to iterate all objects returned. Also, the above syntax is incorrect and would not execute.